# How can I solve the problem of not having required data types in the required file

Tags: c++, structure

So I always keep running into this problem where I am unable to import a file into another file where I need it. I was recently learning about component object modelling and I tried to implement in my recent project. Here is the explanation:

I have a `Triangle` class in a file called `Triangle.h` file.

triangle.h

```
#pragma once
class Tringle{};
```

Then I have a `TriangleProcessor` class that uses these triangles to create a vector of vector of triangles.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "triangle.h"

class TriangleProcessor
{
//
public:
    using vtris = std::vector<Triangle>;
    std::vector<vtris> vvTris;
};
```

Now here is where the problem is. I made a `Renderer` class to draw the triangles. Triangle processor is supposed to hold an instance of this `Renderer` class, so I need to import renderer in Triangle processor. That means I cannot import triangle processor file in renderer, which means I don't have access to any of the data types that it holds or the class itself. That means I cant have a function like this in renderer class as an example:

```
//Dont have access to std::vector<vtris> type
void RenderTriangles(const std::vector<vtris>& vvtris)
{
    //render all triangles
}
```

The same problem arises with all the other files such as input. How can I get around this problem?
Thank you.

Reproducible example.

triangle.h

```
#pragma once

class Triangle{};
```

triangleProcessor.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "triangle.h"
#include "renderer.h"

class TriangleProcessor
{
public:
    TriangleProcessor() = default;

private:
    Renderer renderer;

public:
    using vtris = std::vector<Triangle>;
    std::vector<vtris> vvTris;

private:
    //Want to be able to do this
    void Render()
    {
         renderer.RenderTriangles(vvTris);
    }   
};
```

renderer.h

```
#pragma once
//#include "triangleProcessor.h" Cant do this

class Renderer
{
    //...
    //Error here. Dont have access to std::vector<vtris>
    void RenderTriangles(const std::vector<vtris>& vvtris)
    {
        //render all triangles
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use *forward declarations* to get around this problem.

Comment: You either have to expand the `vtris` type-alias yourself (as shown in [the answer from John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162375/440558)) or use scoping to get the `vtris` alias (i.e. `std::vector<TriangleProcessor::vtris>`).

Comment: Move `using vtris = std::vector<Triangle>;` into `triangle.h` so than code that wants to declare a vector of Triangles can use it instead.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you. That solved the problem.  I didn't know `using vtris = std::vector<Triangle>;` could be defined in triangle class. I was trying to do something similar before but was getting all sorts of redefinition errors.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `std::vector<vtris>` with `std::vector<std::vector<Triangle>>`.

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the problem. Can you explain please.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem, please post a full, reproducible example for us to work on.